# What's wrong with this Hive query to create an external table?

Tags: hadoop, hive, azure-hdinsight

Table gets created by the following HQL, but returns zero rows when subsequently queried.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE default.salesorderdetailx(SalesOrderID int,
       ProductID int,
       OrderQty int,
       LineTotal decimal)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
        FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
        COLLECTION ITEMS TERMINATED BY '\002'
        MAP KEYS TERMINATED BY '\003'
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION 'wasb://mycn-1@my.blob.core.windows.net/mycn-1/hive/warehouse/salesorderdetailx'
```

URL to my blob is as follows:

```
https://my.blob.core.windows.net/mycn-1/hive/warehouse/salesorderdetailx/salesorderdetail.txt
```

My data looks like this:

```
43659,776,1,2024.994000
43659,777,3,6074.982000
43659,778,1,2024.994000
43659,771,1,2039.994000
```

Comment: How many mappers are used when you execute the Hive query?

Comment: Can you share the log ? Is your data location is HDFS location ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in my wasb syntax. Although the various GUI's (Visual Studio, Manage.WindowsAzure.com) indicate the container name as being part of the path--you can see this in the body of my question where I indicated the URL to my blob--it apparently is *NOT*. So, the correct wasb URI in this example should have been `'wasb://mycn-1@my.blob.core.windows.net/hive/warehouse/salesorderdetailx'`. Thanks for everybody who looked at my question. I guess the problem was too obvious for expert eyes to notice. :-/